# Aborted thread start again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller :

**UPDATED**

```
     public ActionResult generateDoc()
        {
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadSleep));
            thread.Start();
            return Json(true);
        }
    public void threadSleep()
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref isThreadComplete, 1);
                thread.Abort();
            }
            public ActionResult callThreadSleep()
            {
                temp = isThreadComplete;
                long thread_comp = Interlocked.Read(ref temp);
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref isThreadComplete, 0);
                return Json(thread_comp);
            }
            //CANCEL GENERATION OF DOCUMENT
            public ActionResult cancelDocumentGen()
            {
                try
                {
                    thread.Abort();
                    Interlocked.Exchange(ref isThreadComplete, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Thread.ResetAbort();
                }
                return Json("");
            }


**UPDATE**

     function doc_creation() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("generateDoc")',
                dataType: "json",
                mtype: "post",
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#docGenModal").show();
                    threadComplete = setInterval(function () {
                        console.log("called");
                        checkDocGen();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
        function checkDocGen() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("callThreadSleep")',
                dataType: "json",
                mtype: "post",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        console.log("hide " + data);
                        clearInterval(threadComplete);
                        $("#docGenModal").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //CANCEL DOCUMENT GENERATION
        function cancelDocGen() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("cancelDocumentGen")',
                dataType: "json",
                mtype: "post",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("successfully cancelled");
                }
            });
        }
```

Onclick of button I called `function checkDocGen()` that call `callThreadSleep` method and click on cancle I called `cancelDocumentGen()` but after aborting it start again..any suggestion or idea?Can I abort like this?..i googled many times, but all examples are much hard to understand for me

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. Can you show us what the thread does and how you start it? My guess would be that a bug in your code starts a new thread.

Comment: @LukasBoersma Yeah updated

Comment: Can you post the `generateDoc` method, too? And, if possible, the method that you use inside the thread?

Comment: @LukasBoersma Yeah done!

Comment: Okay, not sure why this is happening. The only possibility to cancel a thread abortion would be to call `Thread.ResetAbort()`, but you don't do that. Are you sure that you really call `cancelDocumentGen` and that you only call `generateDoc` once?

Comment: @LukasBoersma u right..I forgot to put clearInterval after succession of cancelgenerationDocument ..thanku :) solved